# Is this a good server's load balancing system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, cluster-computing, server

I'm new to this concept and I'm thinking on how to horizontally scale my [Xepler](https://github.com/xeryan/xepler) Node.js framework.

So, the main app on the master server will proxy the request to the first cluster in a queue (maybe retrieved using a shared-memory with redis). Each X requests (depending on the server capabilities, X is decided by me, maybe using a map), the cluster will be moved to the last place in this queue. In this way, all the clusters will receive only a reduced number of requests.

Another app, on another server, each X seconds will make a request to all the clusters in order to check if someone is failed, removing it from the queue (this queue will be on redis?)

All the clusters normally will run an instance of my web framework.

Is for you this a good system of load balancing, or have I completely misunderstanding how works? Thank you guys

edit: that's what I mean (only an example):

```
var http = require('http'),
     https = require('https'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({}),

     clusters = [
        {
            id: 1,
            host: "localhost",
            port: 8080,
            dead : false,
            deadTime : undefined
        },      
        {
            id: 2,
            host: "localhost",
            port: 8081,
            dead : false,
            deadTime : undefined
        }
     ];

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var target = getAvailableCluster();

    if (target != -1) {
        proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://' + target.host + ':' + target.port });

        res.setTimeout(1e3 * 20, function() {
            target.dead = true;
            target.deadTime = new Date().getTime();
            console.log("Cluster " + target.id + " is dead");
        });
    }   
}).listen(80, function() {
    console.log('Proxy listening on port 80..');
});

proxy.on('error', function (error, req, res) {
    var json;
    console.log('proxy error', error);

    if (!res.headersSent)
        res.writeHead(500, { 'content-type': 'application/json' });

    json = { error: 'proxy_error', reason: error.message };
    res.end(JSON.stringify(json));
});

setInterval(function() {
    var cluster,
        currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    for (var i=0; i<clusters.length; i++) {
        cluster = clusters[i];

        if (cluster.dead && (currentTime - cluster.deadTime) > 1000) {
            cluster.dead = false;
            console.log("Cluster " + cluster.id + " is now alive");
        }
    }   
}, 5000);

function getAvailableCluster() {
    var cluster;

    for (var i=0; i<clusters.length; i++) {
        cluster = clusters.shift();
        clusters.push(cluster);

        if (!cluster.dead)      
            return cluster;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What kind of strategy should/can be used depends on the kind of task that runs. e.g. if every request will have approximated the same cpu usage and duration a simple round robin would work. If some type of requests might take longer to process then you might need to use another technique.

Comment: Hmm the task is for a normal website, that has the possibility to upload files (even big files)

Comment: To be clear. You describe some kind of load balancing: distributing tasks depending on the capabilities and capacity of the different servers. But still if it is a good system depends on the use-case. E.g. you might only want to use 50% of your performance to heavy calculations and the other 50% for _easy_ task, to keep your server responsive, ....

Comment: Why are you re-inventing the wheel? There is [hipache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hipache) a reverse proxy/ load balancer which has all the features you need as far as I can see.

Comment: @vanthome Oh nice, as I said, I'm totally new to this world.. I'll take a look to hipache, thank you

Comment: I add is as answer, please accept if it fits your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you re-inventing the wheel? There is [hipache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hipache) a reverse proxy/ load balancer which has all the features you need as far as I can see.